Make nginx dynamically proxy_pass to the same host as in the original request
I'm searching web and trying different variants, but I'm failing to get it work. I'm suspecting that maybe this is not possible with nginx? As actually this is a weird case. But I use two docker containers where first container has some real web site name mapped to second container's IP. In this container selenium connects to the seconds container by the name. I need it for e2e testing purposes as I don't have access to the API backend. But I would like to run nginx that serves statics and proxying API calls to the backend. It works well for static name like
proxy_pass https://www.stage.env;

But I have prod as well https://www.prod.env. And I want nginx to proxy_pass to the same name it got from original request. So I tried these, but nothing works.
proxy_pass $scheme://$http_host$request_uri;

I also tried setting up a variable
set $target "$scheme://$http_host$request_uri";
proxy_pass $target;

As well I tried
proxy_pass $scheme://$host$request_uri;

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Eventually I figured the reason out. It looks like nginx resolves the proxy_pass on start if it's a name. And if the upstream name is dynamically mapped nginx has to have resolver configured. If --network is passed to run command the resolver is available on 127.0.0.11 inside container. So it was enough to add the following line to server directive to make it work.
resolver 127.0.0.11;

